# Trouble on using multiple class object instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpect 2. I am trying to refactoring some spec file in the following way (in order to test with less code similar `User` class object attribute values):

```
let(:user1) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_a => 'invalid_value') }
let(:user2) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_b => 'invalid_value') }
let(:user3) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_c => 'invalid_value') }

[ user1, user2, user3 ].each do |user|
  ...
end
```

However, if I run the above test I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user1' for #<Class:0x00000103ddb158> (NameError)
```

**What is the problem? How can I solve that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your example code inside of a "it" block

```
describe User do

  let(:user1) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_a => 'invalid_value') }
  let(:user2) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_b => 'invalid_value') }
  let(:user3) { Factory(:user, :users_attribute_c => 'invalid_value') }

  it "should be whatever" do

    [ user1, user2, user3 ].each do |user|
      ...    
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475386/trouble-on-setting-the-current-subject